# Service properties not binding to scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have the following service:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var resources = [];

    return {
        resources: resources,
        searchForResources: function(data) { return $http.post('/api/search'); },
    }

}]);
```

And in my controller I have:

```
$scope.resources = MyService.resources;
MyService.searchForResources().then(function(response) {
    MyService.resources = response.data.resources;
});
```

My API call is actually returning the correct data, and MyService.reources is being set, it's just that $scope.resources is not updated with the new value of MyService.resources (I have to do this manually).

Shouldn't the line `$scope.resources = MyService.resources` set up a $watch so that whenever MyService.resources changes, it will also update the value of $scope.resources? How can I make it so this is the case?

**Edit:**
For now, using `$scope.$watch(function() { return SearchService.resources; }, function(newValue) { $scope.resources = newValue; });` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If I can suggest some improvements (but it's not doing exactly the same thing) :

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var resources = [];
    return {
        searchForResources: function(callback) { 
            if (resources) {
                callback(resources)
            } else { 
                $http.post('/api/search').success(function(data){
                  resources = data
                  callback(resources)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

and in the controller :

```
MyService.searchForResources(function(resources){
   $scope.resources = resources
}
```

I hope it can help you...

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to use the `.then()` logic inside my controller. The code I posted was redacted to make the question easier to understand, there is actually a lot more variables in the service and a few other bindings I need to make - your code might be better for my simple example, but it will make things more complicated to work with in my real code.

I understand I can use `$watch` and `$broadcast`, but I was hoping I can get it to work the way I'm imagining in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve the response of the `$http.post` in your service in order to avoid this.  Try something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [ 'myControllers', 'myServices' ]);

angular.module('myServices', [])
.factory('MyService', function($http) {
  
  var MyService = {};
  
  MyService.resources = [];

  MyService.searchForResources = function () {
    return $http.post('/api/search')
    .success(function (response) {
      MyService.resources = response;
    })
    .error(function () {
      MyService.resources = ['error'];
    });
  };
  
  return MyService;

});

angular.module('myControllers', [])
.controller('MyController', function(MyService, $scope) {

  $scope.resources = MyService.resources;
  
  // Don't need both success and error handlers here... can just use then handler instead
  // Doing this for demo purposes.
  MyService
    .searchForResources()
    .success(function () {
      $scope.resources = MyService.resources;
    })
    .error(function() {
      $scope.resources = MyService.resources;
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My App!</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>
      {{ resources }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```